# Change default weights on pretrained models

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a MobileNet model pretrained on imagenet weights, I would like to run it on coco weights. How can I change the default weights on pretrained models?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the pre-trained model when you apply transfer learning comes with an argument e.g. `--weights` to run the model, just look for it and pass the coco weights as parameter